# Calling an ashx from windows phone client

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, ashx

I was looking into some web page, and I found out that it uses some ashx file for autocomplete. This is the javascript method:

```
$("#txtKeyword").autocomplete("xml/autocomplete.ashx", {
            selectFirst: false, scroll: true, extraParams:{type:1}
        });
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to call this file from windows phone app, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can call it like you would call any other webpage (using WebClient for instance). You just need know which parameters must be transmitted to the ashx page. If you can't get them by reading the js, I suggest using Firefox's addon Firebug, or the developper mode of IE, to capture the request.

Comment: can you give an example using WebClient? I can't figure out how to send the parameters (selectFirst,scroll and extraParams).

Comment: I can't know the parameters without having the code of the autocomplete function. That's why I suggest using Firebug to capture the request. Then, you should have something looking like a url (obviously, since it actually is an url). For instance: http://server/xml/autocomplete.ashx?type=1. Once you've got the url, you can use WebClient: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I know that I need to know the parameters, but i thought the (selectFirst,scroll and extraParams) would be enough. And I'm wondering if it has to be a POST or GET. sorry if my question looks dumb, i've never used ashx before

Comment: Don't focus on the ashx, it's just another extension for a webpage. It could have been .php or .html, the problem would remain the same. I don't think the query is POST, it's probably GET. If it's this autocomplete function: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete , then I think the url should be `http://server/xml/autocomplete.ashx?type=1&q=keyword`, where 'keyword' is the word to complete.